# a general approach to derive state space representation from ARMA?

Tags: arima, state-space-models

I see that the likes of this question has been asked many times but I'm just wondering whether there is a general approach to write ARMA models in state space representation? I have an exam in a few days, and although I know that an ARMA can be written as many different SS models, I have not been able to write down one myself, and struggle to see the process in which we go from one to the other.

Can someone point me to a basic reference, or point out how it is done for a simple model? Suppose we have ARMA(1,1)

$ y_t = \phi_1 y_{t-1} + u_t + \rho u_{t-1}$

Comment: The example model that you give has 1 AR term & 1 moving average term so the correct notation is ARMA(1,1) or ARIMA(1,0,1).

Comment: I have some slides that show how it is done: https://robjhyndman.com/talks/ABS3.pdf

Comment: Hamilton ["Time Series Analysis"](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691042893/time-series-analysis) has a section on that with multiple (I think 3) alternative state-space representations for ARIMA models. Pretty usable as far as I can remember.

Comment: Thanks everyone (and the mistake is corrected). @RobHyndman the slides are quite informative thank you.